# JQuery: How to create a lightbox to open up a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

Using JQuery, how do I create a lightbox effect but instead of display a single photo - I want to display an HTML document within the lightbox.

Essentially, if you have every used Facebook - they do this effect all the time. Instead of going to a new webpage to send a message, it just pops up the message HTML form inline on the current page.

**UPDATE**

Does anyone have more information on JQuery Dialog built-in capabilities. It appears I might be able to have a JQuery Dialog load an external web page ... but am having a difficult time finding the info.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the lightbox effect?

Comment: I'm ideally looking for something built into the core but if a plugin is required, that's fine. I'm just looking to be pointed into the direction of where I can find to do this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

[This contains all you need!](http://www.fortysomething.ca/mt/etc/archives/006978.php)

Comment: that's a pretty relevant link to this question

Comment: Why is it that *Shadowbox* gets so little publicity? It's an excellent system.

Comment: Because people like me have never heard of Shadowbox. It's part of how well you advertise your product as well.

Comment: Well I always considered Shadowbox to be fairly high profile. I guess not. It's probably the best one I've come across, though.

Comment: I checked it out and I like it :)

Comment: @Doug, Inquisitor - What's the link for shadowbox?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular JQuery based solutions that can do IFrames is [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

It is no longer maintained apparently, but should be fine to use right now and also features a number of alternatives on its front page.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be **exactly** what you're looking for, but aside from the Lightbox plugin, you could try jQueryUI's [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: This interesting given that it's apart of the core library. I'll have to look into seeing if the JQuery UI Dialog supports opening up HTML links

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/example).

FancyBox is a jQuery plugin for displaying images, html content and multi-media in a Mac-style "lightbox" that floats overtop of web page.